# Setting timeout for all the ProxyPass mappings in Apache Server mod_proxy directive

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

**What I have and works:**

I'm using *Apache HTTPD 2.2* for proxy requests. I have multiple *ProxyPass* mappings:

```
ProxyRequests On 
<Proxy *>
AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost Off

ProxyPass /a http://some_ip/
ProxyPassReverse /a http://some_ip/

ProxyPass /b http://some_other_ip/
ProxyPassReverse /b http://some_other_ip/

...
```

This works well.

**What I want:**

Some of my requests are taking longer, so they timed out giving me a ***Proxy Error - Reason: Error reading from remote server***.

I want to set `timeout` for all of my requests. Can I do this without having to add `timeout=... KeepAlive=On` for every `ProxyPass` mapping?

I currently have something like:

```
ProxyPass /a http://some_ip/ timeout=1200 KeepAlive=On
ProxyPassReverse /a http://some_ip/

ProxyPass /b http://some_other_ip/ timeout=1200 KeepAlive=On
ProxyPassReverse /b http://some_other_ip/

... and i do this for all my ProxyPass mappings
```

Can I tell Apache in some way to add `timeout` and `KeepAlive` parameters for all the mappings? Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:** I also tried using the **mod_reqtimeout** directive directly, but it did not do the trick for me:

```
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so

RequestReadTimeout header=1200 body=1200
```

Comment: The ProxyRequests directive should usually be set off when using ProxyPass.  Open proxy servers are dangerous both to your network and to the Internet at large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution by my own. You can set the timeout using directly the `ProxyTimeout` directive of `mod_proxy` :

```
ProxyRequests On 
<Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost Off

ProxyTimeout 1200
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the Apache documentation, if the *ProxyTimeout* configuration directive is *not specified*, the global/vhost setting of *Timeout* is used and in effect. So if the backend is taking longer than *Timeout* seconds, Apache will close the connection (!).

So even though *ProxyTimeout* has a default of 300s, you pretty much need to specify it anyway to make sure it is in effect.